# Python Pandas Technical Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, technical-indicator

I have a pandas dataframe of EOD stock data grouped as follows:

```
    ticker   date    open   high    low     close   share_volume
0   AFSLN0000   2021-09-03  25.5    29.0    25.5    27.5    758
1   AFSLN0000   2021-09-02  24.2    25.0    24.2    25.0    3881
2   AFSLN0000   2021-09-01  24.2    24.3    24.2    24.2    1660

1672    ACLN0000    2019-09-04  38.0    38.0    38.0    38.0    7500
1673    ACLN0000    2019-09-03  38.5    38.9    38.2    38.9    1286
1674    ACLN0000    2019-09-02  38.9    39.2    38.2    39.0    22095

1675 rows × 7 columns
```

I want to choose the first ticker run the technical anlysis, plot a chart etc and then do the same with the next ticker till I finish with all the tickers in the dataframe. How can I do that.

yfinance has no data for my country and I am not programming expert.

I think I need a for loop but cant figure out how to do it

Comment: `for ticker, subdf in df.groupby('ticker'): # do something with subdf`